# ServiceStack.Text JsConfig changes globally

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-text

Is there a way to avoid `JsConfig` changes globally?

I only want to customize the configuration when serialize my json, and don't affect others places.

```
JsConfig.AlwaysUseUtc = true;
JsConfig.ExcludeTypeInfo = true;

JsConfig<DateTime>.RawSerializeFn = (DateTime time) =>
{
    return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "\"{0}\"", time.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff"));
};
JsConfig<DateTime?>.RawSerializeFn = (DateTime? time) =>
{
    if (time.HasValue)
        return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "\"{0}\"", time.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff"));
    return "null";
};

// avoid loss of precision
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
JsConfig<long>.RawSerializeFn = (long num) =>
{
    if (num > 9007199254740991L || num < -9007199254740991L)
        return string.Format( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "\"{0}\"", num);
    return num.ToString();
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You can specify a scope of change using with static `JsConfig.With(...)` method.

See the [4.0.48 Release Notes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/docs/2015/release-notes.md#custom-serialized-responses) for an example. Just use the second form, like this:

```
using(JsConfig.With(new Config { ... }) {
    ... operations with overridden JsConfig settings
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't see there is a way to customize `RawSerializeFn` in `JsConfig.With()`.  yep?